# Enviar funcion con parametros JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
<td border="1" onClick="myFunction()">
```

Estoy tratando de hacer lo siguiente para poder recibir un valor en la funcion myFunction(variable).

```
<td border="1" onClick="myFunction(variable)">
```

Pero me envia el siguiente error:

> is not defined
>       at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de la función para ver mas a fondo que problema tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer va de la siguiente forma:

```js
function myFunction(mensaje) {
  console.log(mensaje);
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td onClick="myFunction('Celda A')">Celda A</td>
    <td onClick="myFunction('Celda B')">Celda B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Nota:

> Si quieres enviar algún tipo de variable y te da error, deberás poner mas código en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para usar variables, debes dejar de escribir código embebido. Ademas de una mala practica es mas poderoso el js en scripts separados.

De donde sacas 'variable' en el html?
Debes explicar mas el problema.